# Python: Time of day to execute

Tags: python

I have written a small script to fetch instant stock prices.

```
#script to get stock data

from __future__ import print_function
import urllib
import lxml.html
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import time

stocks=["stock1","stock2","stock3","stock4","stock5"]

while True:
 f=open('./out.txt', 'a+')
 for x in stock:
  url = "http://someurltofetchdata/"+x
  code   = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  html   = lxml.html.fromstring(code)
  result = html.xpath('//td[@class="LastValue"][position() = 1]')
  result = [el.text_content() for el in result]
  f.write(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + x + ' ' + result[0])
  f.write("\n")
 f.close()
```

I want that code to fetch data only on hours the stock market is open which means on trading hours. (09:00 to 12:30 and 13:30 to 17:30).

Could you please suggest a method to perform the scheduling implicitly on the code? (Not on the OS level)

Comment: cron is your best fried. Resolving this on the application level yourself makes not much sense. Use the tools that are working for decades.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot use cron (which is the simplest way to accomplish the task), you can add this to your code. It will download data if within given time range, sleep for 60 seconds and then run again.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M')
    if '0900' <= now <= '1230' or '1330' <= now <= '1730':
        # your code starting with f=open('./out.txt', 'a+')
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: This code is intended to run on Windows. It is, however still possible to schedule it but I want to modify the code to a standalone Windows Service running on background and starting at boot. That is why I did not consider a scheduling solution like cron.

eumiro, thank you, your solution helps me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [APScheduler](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/)

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(hours=3)
def some_job():
    print "Decorated job"

sched.configure(options_from_ini_file)
sched.start()
```

You can also specify a time.date

```
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, datetime(2009, 11, 6, 16, 30, 5), ['text'])
```

Obviously you'll have to write some code to turn these on and off `sched.start()` `sched.stop()`at the relevant times , but then it will go and get the data as often as you have set on the decorator automatically. You could even schedule the schedule!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule this script on Windows, please use [task schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)[image]. 
It has GUI to configuration, and pretty easy. For Linux, crontab will be better. And most important, you don't need to modify your code, and much stable for long term running.